# debian uwsgi not built with ssl support

Tags: ssl, websocket, debian, uwsgi, apt

i recently installed uwsgi 2.0.3 on debian via aptitude.
now i am trying to run the default websocket example, but the log tells me:

```
you need to build uWSGI with SSL support to use the websocket handshake api function !!!
[uwsgi-perl error] unable to complete websocket handshake at ...
```

I am a bit puzzled, since i cannot find a ssl-plugin and i can't see any options to turn on/off ssl-support. I really want to stick with aptitude, installing uwsgi manually is not preferred, beside i have no clue how to enable it manually either.

Does anyone know how to enable uwsgi-ssl support in debian the aptitude way?

btw.
i also removed uwsgi with aptitude remove --purge uwsgi
installed libssl-dev and reinstalled uwsgi
but without luck :(

Answer (score 1):

You must compile uwsgi yourself if you want the SSL support. Debian hasn't packaged a version of uwsgi with SSL support. I know, it's annoying for updates ... but you haven't the choice.

You just need to run `apt-get install build-essential python python-dev libssl-dev`, then `python uwsgiconfig.py` ...

Comment: what a pity, i asked the package maintainer if there is any chance to get this integrated... thx for reply